# R plot doesn't shows on Mac but the same plot shows on Windows

Tags: r, macos, plot, graphics

Yesterday I bought a Mac (M1 processor) and today I installed R and R Studio. I tried to plot the same code in a Windows machine and my Mac, but the plot only shows on Windows. On Mac the "plots" window only shows a white box and if I try to export it, the same white box appear.

The code is:

```
library(ggshakeR)
 
 library(worldfootballR)
 
 single_player <- fb_player_scouting_report("https://fbref.com/en/players/f586779e/Tammy-Abraham", pos_versus = "primary")
 
 pizza <- plot_pizza(data = single_player, type = "single", template = "forward",    colour_poss = "#41ab5d", colour_att = "#fec44f", season = "Last 365 Days", colour_def = "#de2d26", theme = "dark")
 pizza
```

Comment: Does the plot show up if you use the RGui instead of RStudio? I assume when you say "export the plot" you are using the button in RStudio? What happens if you try `ggsave` - does the file show the graph? Maybe install the `Cairo` package (if it isn't already) and try `ggsave` with `type = "cairo"`.

Comment: Even in RGui the plot does not show.Neither with ggsave or with the Cairo package.

Comment: Did you install XQuartz? It's described on [R's download page](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/).

Comment: Yes, I did, the result is the same, just a white box when plotting.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - my R used to stop responding when I plotted, irrespective of the R version or the library I used. I solved it by rebooting my M1 Mac in safe mode, and plotting worked while in safe mode. And luckily it kept working afterwards when I restarted in normal mode.

This is apple support [instruction on how to reboot in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201262).

They say

> Safe mode can help you determine whether an issue is being caused by
> software that loads when your Mac starts up.

Comment: This just worked for me! Thank you!