# ggplot2 on MacOS (with M1 chip) freezes R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I updated Rstudio to 2022.02.3 build 492 on my MacBook Pro w/ M1 chip and find that Rstudio won't create ggplot2 plots.  The following simple graph won't complete.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

aa <- tibble(a=1:100, b=runif(100))

aa %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x=a,y=b))
```

I updated to the latest base R to solve the issue, but it did not resolve the problem.

> R.version
> _
> platform       aarch64-apple-darwin20
> arch           aarch64
> os             darwin20
> system         aarch64, darwin20
> status
> major          4
> minor          2.1
> year           2022
> month          06
> day            23
> svn rev        82513
> language       R
> version.string R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
> nickname       Funny-Looking Kid

EDITED:   Running the few lines of code above on the R command line does not solve the problem.  This suggests it's an R issue (and not related to Rstudio).

Does anyone have any suggestions that might help me figure out why this is occurring or how to resolve this issue?

UPDATE:  I've installed the latest base R and Rstudio and rebooted.
I now receive the dreaded "Error in grid.Call" message when I try to generate the graphic.

From [Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : Polygon edge not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581440/error-in-grid-calll-textbounds-as-graphicsannotxlabel-xx-xy-polygon)

it seems the issue is that R can't access to Arial font, for some reason.   The very last comment in that post is key.  It suggests adding +theme(text=element_blank()) [removing all text from the plot].

A graphic is generated, confirming the font issue.   The problem is none of the suggestions that post seem to clear the problem.

Comment: Does base r plot work? Say plot(1:100, runif(100))

Comment: Nope.  Same behavior as when I run my code on the R command line.   No graph appears.

Comment: It seems to not be a ggplot issue then. I doubt I can fix it because it's probably something peculiar to your installation. What is the output  of `capabilities()` and `dev.cur()` ?

Comment: Perhaps you could try different settings in RStudio under General > Graphics > Backend.

Comment: @Hugh Not sure the best way to show the output.  So, 
capabilities()
       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE 
     cledit       iconv         NLS       Rprof     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE       FALSE        TRUE

Comment: @Hugh
dev.cur()
null device 
          1

Comment: See my "UPDATE" in the original post.

Comment: After digging around using Google to find a solution, I tried installeding the "showtext" package, and running showtext_auto() inside my script.   This solved the problem and the graphic was generated properly.

Comment: Alas, I restarted my machine, and loading the showtext library and running "showtext_auto()" does solve the problem of the simple plotting script.  However, a more complicated script does not yet work.

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73081500/11610199

Restart mac in safe mode. 

Then go back to normal mode. Weird.